# SimpleXmlIterator memory usage

Tags: php, xmlreader

Is it possible to force SimpleXmlIterator not to load the whole xml file (2.7G) into memory? Expected it to iterate through the file only when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [XMLReader](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php). You can use it to iterate over the XML file element by element, reading only small chunks at a time (and if you wish - you can even load these elements to SimpleXMLElement).